# Client-side templating, server-side templating or raw cloning&editing stub DOM elements client-side?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a page showing a list of objects (e.g. books).
This list can programmatically increase through client-side interaction.
Which is a good way to create new "books" in the DOM?

I'd like to create an invisible stub of the object in the DOM and then clone it n-times, each time editing proprieties (e.g. like book's title and thumb).

Which is the best practice?

Performance are not the main focus. Code manutenibility and simplicity is my focus.
I already use jQuery.

Comment: There are TONS of projects for this basic CRUD stuff. Easiest for you and the user? Show a table, allow a user to add a row. Has been done countless times in jQuery before.

Comment: @Konerak I've looked around but I've not found an explicit best practice, so I ask here to understand which is the common way to handle this and which are the latest solutions. Sorry if looks trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid "clones" and use a client-side templating solution like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). Load your templates (preloaded in variables, via AJAX, whatever), cache them (in objects, arrays, variables, whatever) for reuse then build them via jQuery:

```
//the data
var data = {
    text : 'foo'
}

//HTML template string
var templateString = '<div><span>{{text}}</span></div>';

//render contents to template
var templateWithData = Mustache.render(templateString,data);

//build using jQuery
//should now be a div that has a span that contains foo
var newElement = $(templateWithData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a templating engine. My personal favorite is [icanhaz.js](http://icanhazjs.com/) but there are a lot of other solutions available.

Answer (score 0):

You´re better of with a Databinding Framework/Engine instead of template engines.

Databinding frameworks like [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com)

```
//View (Template)
<form data-bind="submit: addItem">
New item:
<input data-bind='value: itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
  <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: itemToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
  <p>Your items:</p>
  <select multiple="multiple" width="50" data-bind="options: items"> </select>
</form>

// ViewModel - Here's my data model
var SimpleListModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
    this.addItem = function() {
        if (this.itemToAdd() != "") {
            this.items.push(this.itemToAdd()); // Adds the item. Writing to the "items" observableArray causes any associated UI to update.
            this.itemToAdd(""); // Clears the text box, because it's bound to the "itemToAdd" observable
        }
    }.bind(this);  // Ensure that "this" is always this view model
};

ko.applyBindings(new SimpleListModel(["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"]));
```

[Try it in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/)